# Is it grammatically correct to omit a comma after dialogue ending in an ellipsis?

Tags: commas, writing-style, ellipses, dialogue

I know that Grammarly isn't always correct but before tonight, I didn't know punctuation directly after an ellipsis was grammatically correct, even in special circumstances such as dialogue.

Unless it's stylistic, Grammarly is insisting that what I currently have is incorrect (see photo below).

The sentence in question is:

> “You want to marry me…” she led off in a breathy voice as she
>   grabbed my shirt collar. “Not out of love, but for mutual benefits.”

I would have never thought to include a comma there, even then, a comma would look so odd. From what I've read, it seems stylistic, but I'm asking is it grammatically correct to leave it as is?

At this point, I think I'd rather omit the ellipsis entirely and replace with a comma rather than add a comma to the end of the ellipsis.

[image]

Comment: Feel free to ignore Grammarly. You can use whichever style you wish. (Unless you're following a specific style guide.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm planning to self-publish, I'm not sure if that matters or not

Comment: What point of grammar do you suspect might be in play / at stake here?

Comment: Hi, Margaret. May I refer you to my answer at [**Punctuation of a direct quote**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103778/punctuation-of-a-direct-quote) (which question is a possible duplicate). I'm sure it encompasses tricky final punctuation within the quote. // Also, errors etc of punctuation are not considered to come within the domain of _grammaticality_ on ELU (though they are equally important).

Comment: @MargaretBelt Simply pick a style you like and use it consistently.