# Punctuating Dialogue That Runs with Sentence

Tags: punctuation, dialogue

How would I punctuate this line of dialogue?

**Example 1** (minimal punctuation): Jane handed me the phone with a “here she is” before leaving the room.
**Example 2:** (comma): Jane handed me the phone with a "here she is," before leaving the room.
**Example 3** (Capitalization + Comma) Jane handed me the phone with a "Here she is," before leaving the room.

**Other?**

Thank you!

Comment: In such sentence,  the comma should be avoided. Considering that "Here she is" is a verbatim, capitalization is recommended.

Comment: Your first version is correct — no comma, no capitals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Punctuation of a Direct Quote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103778/punctuation-of-a-direct-quote) (where more flexible modern approaches to introductory and terminal stops (eg commas) are discussed. [Punctuation in an indirect quotation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306363/punctuation-in-an-indirect-quotation/306370#306370) may also help. And [How to punctuate one-word {/part-} quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215253/how-to-punctuate-one-word-quotes-in-a-sentence/232548#232548) looks spot on.